# Lazy-load external JavaScript in one of AngularJS controller

Tags: angularjs

Some of my routes needs functionality from external JS. I don't want to load them all at once since those JS are needed only in certain routes (e.g. `/upload` needs some JS for photo uploading, `/photos` needs another JS for lightbox, `/funny` needs JS for animation stuff, etc).

What's the best practice for lazily loading those external JavaScripts?

Those routes can be accessed multiple times (e.g. user can go to `/upload` then `/photos` then `/upload` again)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I know to handle cases like this is using the "resolve" method of a route. This method can be used to define a dependency to be loaded before the route's controller is instantiated. One of the different possible return types of this method is a promise. Thus you might use this to start loading your external JavaScript code asynchronously and return a promise that is resolved as soon as your external scripts are loaded.

The documentation for this can be found here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider in the "when" section.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what Alex has stated, if you will be lazy loading AngularJS artefacts such as controllers and directives, you would have to use the relevant provider to register them instead of the module API. Artefacts registered using the module API after the application has been bootstrapped, will not be available to the application. For example, you would define a lazy controller like this...

```
$controllerProvider.register('SomeLazyController', function($scope)
{
   $scope.key = '...'; 
});
```

instead of this...

```
angular.module('app').controller('SomeLazyController', function($scope)
{
    $scope.key = '...';
});
```

I have written a blog post detailing this as well as how to use the 'resolve' method that Alex speaks about, to implement lazy loading in AngularJS. http://ify.io/lazy-loading-in-angularjs/

Answer (score 2):

@alex3683's answer is probably the correct AngularJS way, but I don't grasp the concept, so instead I make use of jQuery's `getScript()`. So, in CoffeeScript:

```
yourModule.factory 'foo', ->
    $.getScript 'https://script-to-load', ->
        # whatever you want to do once the script is loaded
```

And just call it from your controller. Since AngularJS services are lazy and singleton, this will only load the script once.