# Angularjs : can i inject dependency in app dynamically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection

I have defined drawerApp on my js . On click of button i am loading partial and there require js file. I need to inject some loaded js into my current drawerApp is there any way to inject in app?

Currentlt  config. is as below.

**JavaScript:**

```
drawerApp.config([ '$interpolateProvider','$controllerProvider','$compileProvider', '$filterProvider', '$provide',
    function ($interpolateProvider,$controllerProvider,$compileProvider, $filterProvider, $provide) {

    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{[{');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('}]}');

    drawerApp.register =
        {
            controller: $controllerProvider.register,
            directive: $compileProvider.directive,
            filter: $filterProvider.register,
            factory: $provide.factory,
            service: $provide.service
        };
}]);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lazy-load external JavaScript in one of AngularJS controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12532890/lazy-load-external-javascript-in-one-of-angularjs-controller)